# How to convert to integer number if first decimal is zero in R?

Tags: r, integer, decimal

I have a set of numbers, in a vector, where the first and subsequent digits are zeros. How do I convert them into integers and count them?
I have been looking for a function to do this in R but seems there is not.

```
numbers <- c(2.857700, 3.566220, 3.071429, 3.652143, 3.587585, 3.317100, 3.500000, 4.047454, 3.700000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
```

In this example, the output should be: 2.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: The expected output is:    2.857700, 3.566220, 3.071429, 3.652143, 3.587585, 3.317100, 3.500000, 4.047454, 3.700000, 1, 1. And then I want to count the number of integer numbers, probably with `sum(numbers == as.integer())`. Final output should be 2, as there are only 2 integer numbers in the vector.

Comment: `numbers %>% {round(.)==.}`

Comment: Well, for one, R can't mix integers and floating point numbers in the same vector. They all most be the same type. So "integers" will be printed with ".0000". And rather than saying "the first decimal is a zero" it sounds like you mean "the first digit after the decimal point is zero". But what would happen with "1.005" which is clearly not an "integer". Why do you need to convert them? Is it just for display purposes?

Comment: You are right @MrFlick, I wanted to say "the first digit after the decimal point is zero". I don't mind what happen after the first digit. If the first digit is zero, then it should be converted into an integer. I need to count how many integers I have to make something afterwards.

Comment: What about `c(1.2000000,1.9999999)` , which returns `1.2` and `2.0` when printed? Do you always have only `n` decimal places at the point of creating `numbers`? Are you referencing the underlying value or the printed value?

Comment: I always have the same number of decimal places, @thelatemail. I am referencing the printed value.

Comment: @TomasMarina the printed value is going to depend on what you have set in options... what exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like this?

```
numbers <- c(2.857700, 3.566220, 3.071429, 3.652143, 3.587585, 3.317100, 3.500000, 4.047454, 3.700000, 1.000000, 1.000000)

sum(floor((numbers - floor(numbers)) * 10) == 0)
#[1] 4
```

The last line returns the number of floats in `numbers` where the first digit after the decimal point is zero; to check, let's print those numbers

```
numbers[floor((numbers - floor(numbers)) * 10) == 0]
#[1] 3.071429 4.047454 1.000000 1.000000
```

Comment: thanks for your help! However, I've just figured out that I need to count also numbers where the first and the subsequent digits are zeros.

Comment: @TomasMarina You need to give a reproducible example with expected output; I'm not sure what you mean. Please edit your original question.

Comment: In this example the output should be 2.    `numbers <- c(2.857700, 3.566220, 3.071429, 3.652143, 3.587585, 3.317100, 3.500000, 4.047454, 3.700000, 1.000000, 1.000000)`

Comment: @TomasMarina Not clear. *"numbers where the first and the subsequent digits are zeros"* Do you mean you want to test *sequentially* if more and more digits after the decimal point are zero? Or whether *all* digits after the decimal point are zero? The latter case is trivial (`round(numbers) == numbers`).

Comment: I mean to count only those numbers where first and all the following  digits (i.e. second, third, etc) are zeros. Is it clear now?

Comment: @TomasMarina That sounds very different from the original question you posted; changing the main problem statement of a question is generally considered poor form as you're basically wasting time of other potential SO respondents who have been trying to help. That aside, this sounds like a trivial `sum(round(numbers) == numbers)`, which is what @OganM posted much earlier as a comment.